# Why would android forget some assets?

Tags: android, image, loading, assets

My Problem: **Only one image will actually load from the assets folder.** I have all the images there and when I try to access **any** of them **I don't get an error.** By actually load I mean it shows the image on the screen. When I load the other images the whole screen comes up white.

In every instance I am loading the whole image to the whole screen.

If I were to put the image as a fourth its size in the middle of the screen then there is a white rectangle there. The image is supposedly in the .apk because I don't get an error for the game trying to find it. However if I were to load this one image then everything words fine.

The one image that works find is a .png image and I tried to load the others as a .png but it does not work.

Any advice on where to start?

---

I load the images through the AssetManager.readAsset() as an input stream and then use the bitmap factory to get the image as a bitmap. Afterwards I load the bitmap into open gl and draw the region I want. However, the problem is only my first image I ever started using works at the moment. Could there be something wrong with a file that eclipse generates?

Comment: I just replicated how I made the other image with a new red box image... the red box came up white!!! :(

Comment: I have pages and pages of code (game)... what code would be useful? It was working perfectly before... why would it stop now? I have been drawing images all day and not changed any of the code. Loading it from the assets folder and my one atlas I was using before which is a .png is working now. However, all other images are not working atm because they are newer. I am restarting phone, eclipse and then will clean project and get back to you on results.

Comment: So get this, I did everything I said above. Now I don't even get the white, but if I use my Loading_Atlas.png it works every time. Really starting to piss me off. I restarted everything, cleaned, made new images... ect. Still... no luck or anything. What would you all try next?

Comment: Ok, so I opened the .apk file and all the images are there with the right name. The image has to be loading and being read, but for some reason instead of it showing the correct colors it is showing white. I changed the resolution and nothing different. I looked at other people describing my problem and they forgot to blend their image, that is not the case here. Infact I don't want to blend the image because I just want to show a red square that I drew in gimp, but it is not working. The more complicated atlas which is a png image is still working of course... makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Turns out that one image that worked had a bit depth of 32 and the other ones only had a 24 bit depth.

The solution is to open up the image in gimp, add an alpha channel (makes it 32 bit), and save it as a .png file. Then read the details and it should say it is 32 bit.

Thanks guy! :)

---

Also note that images have to be by power of 2. For example it needs to be 1024 by 1024.

Answer (score 0):

Some png bug android.

Just try to open them and save them with gimp. Sometimes it solves the problem.

Comment: I tried it before and just tried it again. Did not work. Also tried to make a new image. Nothing... used .jpeg... nothing... :(